# Flutter Web: Uncaught (in promise) Error: [cloud_firestore/unknown] NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'includeMetadataChanges'

Tags: firebase, flutter, web

Flutter Web:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [cloud_firestore/unknown] NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'includeMetadataChanges'...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJPKi.png)

pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
```

index.html

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.3/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Code

```
class UserNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<UserModel>> {
  UserNotifier([List<UserModel>? state])
      : super(state = <UserModel>[]) {     
    fatchData(); // It's same as initState();
  }
 

  Future fatchData() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').get();
    final List<UserModel> users = [];
    snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
      UserModel _user = UserModel.fromSnapshot(document);
      users.add(_user);
    });
  }
}
```

There is no null in the data. What is the solution?

Comment: I changed firebase-firestore version 8.2.3 to 7.22.1, and it works well.
( firebase-analytics, firebase-firestore )

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue in the latest version. Try the older versions to solve the issue.
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4127

This version worked for me, in `pubspec.yaml`

```
firebase_core: ^0.5.3
firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
```

In `index.html`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```